# Comic book about dinosaurs in space

Tags: story-identification, comics, dinosaurs

The comic book I'm talking about is about this one T. rex-like dinosaur being frozen in a cryo-pod after trying to rejoin his father on Earth, who was holding off some sort of black ooze from getting to the other dinosaurs. The dinosaurs were evacuating earth to escape from this black ooze. Eventually, humans dig up the remains of the battle and the cryopod. The group of humans want to excavate a fuel source from that area, and have hired or have forced a doctor to help them. The doctor brings along his daughter, who is the main companion for the t-rex dinosaur. The humans activate the cryopod and release the T. rex dinosaur. After a skirmish, the black ooze is also released. The ooze corrupts and absorbs the humans except for the doctor's daughter, and the dinosaur takes the daughter with him to protect her. I think that's what happens. Then a distress signal is sent out somehow, and a group of intergalactic dinosaurs come and rescue them. One of them is a grumpy triceratops. Another is a really tech-savvy, green, female dinosaur.

Comment: See https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question. When was this comic likely to have been written? Any indications of style (manga/western etc)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! For some help improving this question, see [our amazing guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999). For starters, around when did you read this?